# How to add closing XML tags with sed

Tags: sed, search, replace, xml

I have the following example in the XML doc:

```
<meta name=Originator content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-6">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15"/>
```

While running the following sed command:

```
'/./{H;$!d} ; x ; s@<meta\([^/>]*\)>@<meta\1/>@g'
```

I'm obtaining the following result:

```
<meta name=Originator content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-6">
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document/>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15"/>
```

Where the closing slash is missing for the first example due to the slash between text and html.

If however I modify my sed command to:

```
'/./{H;$!d} ; x ; s@<meta\([^>]*\)>@<meta\1/>@g'
```

Then I have double slash on the third example:

```
<meta name=Originator content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-6"/>
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document/>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15"//>
```

Any idea on how to cover both of those cases?

Comment: Should _every_ instance of `>` be preceded by a `/` in your file? Can you safely run a command that will add a `/` before any `>` unless one is already there?

Comment: `xmlstarlet` would be able to correct the document using `xmlstarlet fo -R -H file.html >newfile.html`. I don't see why you would want to use `sed` for this.

Comment: Hi @terdon, every instance of the tag meta, yes, but nor for other tags.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I wil try xmlsarlet and let you know. In fact, I do have some html files converted from docx that I try to then convert to XML.

Comment: @Kusalananda sounds like an answer, no? I had assumed the dedicated parsers would just choke.

Comment: It seems my html is too nasty for xmlstarlet to work, getting errors like `input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0x20 0x32 0x30 0x32`

Comment: @terdon I didn't want to submit it as an answer as I can only see a broken fragment of the user's data.

Comment: @Miloš I can say nothing about that as I can't see your document.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks! Before exploring `xmlstarlet`, I would prefer to stick to the initial question and find a solution with sed.

Comment: @Miloš the problem is that `sed` is the wrong tool for the job. It might work in your specific case, but we cannot know unless you share the entire file, and as a general rule, using naive tools like sed to parse structured document formats is very, very fragile. For example, what if you have a tag that spans multiple lines? I'll post a simple (perl, not sed) answer, but it really isn't the Right Way©.

Comment: word produces garbage html, always has.  personally, i'd be tempted to use `pandoc` to convert it from html to markdown (or just use `lynx -dump` and manually add the markdown formatting), edit it to clean up the markdown if/as needed, and then use `markdown` to convert it back to html.   That should give clean html that can be processed easily with xmlstarlet....and it will remove the copious amounts of garbage span and div etc tags that MS Word adds in.

Comment: @cas, I fully understand the approach is not the best one or maybe even a completely wrong one, however, I am applying this as a quick fix to an existing prototype with the goal to make it work. Thanks for sharing the idea of pandoc usage, etc. And fully agree, docx to html converter produces a loooot of garbage.

Comment: Try this : sed "s/\(.*<meta.*[^\/]\)\/*>/\1\/>/"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, I need to include an obligatory warning: using naive text parsing tools to parse [XH]TML is a bad idea. It will fail very often, is not robust to any changes in the input and is very likely to silently do something that breaks your document. You should *always* try to use a dedicated XML parser instead.

That said, if the following assumptions are true, you can use the solution below:

1. None of your tags span multiple lines.
2. All `<meta` opening tags, and only those tags, need a `/>` to close.
3. You can never have a `>` inside a tag. I don't actually know the XML specs well enough to know if that can happen, perhaps within a `name=`?

If the above are true, try:

```
$ sed -E 's|(<meta [^>]*[^/])>|\1/>|' file.xml 
<meta name=Originator content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-6/>
<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Documen/>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15"/>
```

Comment: Great, that solved my issue!

Comment: @cas yeah, it has all sorts of problems. It's a bad solution but I promised "quick 'n dirty". I did fix the last character issue by including it in the capture group, that was a silly mistake, thanks.

Comment: @cas yeah, but that will add an extra tag in `<meta name=foo / >`. Which, now that I think of it might be a good thing, not really sure.

Comment: Cool, thanks @cas. I removed it from my answer.